# Given a continuous random variable, Can I say that $P(X<A)=P(X \leq A) $ from continuity?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I'm trying to understand how hard/soft inequalities can be manipulated into each other with continuous random variables. For example, the C.D.F. of a continuous random variable $X$ is given by:
$P(X\leq x)$.

I'd like to know if I can say that $P(X\leq x)=P(X<x)$ as by the definition of a continuous random variable $P(X=x)=0$

A specific example:
$X$ is a continuous random variable, with P.D.F. $\frac{3}{17}\cdot t^2$ for $t\in\left[-2,1\right]$ else $0$
In this case:
$P(X\leq -1)=\frac{3}{17}\cdot\int_{-2}^{-1}{t^2dt}=\frac{3}{17}\cdot\left.\frac{t^3}{3}\right|_{-2}^{-1}=\frac{3}{17}\cdot\left(\frac{-1}{3}-\frac{-8}{3}\right)=\frac{7}{17}$
using the C.D.F.
Can I use that result to conclude that $P(X<-1)=\frac{7}{17}$ as $P(X=-1)=0$?

Comment: Yes you can, since the events $\{ X < x\}$ and $\{X = x \}$ are disjoint. Hence you can use the additivity of the probability measure P to obtain $P(X \leq x) = P(X < x) + P(X = x)$. Together with the assumption that $X$ is continuously distributed this directly yields the claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(X\leq x)$ is the disjoint union of the sets $(X<x)$ and $(X=x)$. So $P(X\leq x)=P(X<x)+P(X=x)=P(X<x)$.